# Simplifying and evaluating mathematical strings

Tags: string, vb.net, math, ncalc

What would be the simplest way to **evaluate/simplify** a mathematical string in **VB**?

For example: `"k*k+(5+2*5)k+k"` would simplify to `"k^2+15k+k"` and `"5^2+3"` would evaluate to `28`.

To evaluate, I'm using **NCalc** by simply using the evaluate function, but it doesn't simplify expressions. 
What would be the simplest way of simplifying the equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Math.NET Symbolics](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/).

It doesn't "know" about the implied multiplication for (a)b, so you would have to work out how to insert an `*` if you can't require it.

```
Imports MathNet.Symbolics
Imports Expr = MathNet.Symbolics.SymbolicExpression

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim a = Expr.Parse("k*k+(5+2*5)*k+k")
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(Expr.Parse("5^2+3"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> 16*k + k^2
>   28

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed I think.